# SubViewOneController’s view not appearing (Obj-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to find my way into Obj-C (iPhone) following [this](http://theappleblog.com/2009/04/15/iphone-dev-sessions-create-a-navigation-based-application/#) tutorial.
Unfortunately there must be something missing in the code because the view of `SubViewOneController` does not appear.

Someone proposed a fix to this in the comments:

> The solution to the `SubViewOneController’s` view not appearing is that
>   you need to tell the controller that the view will be initialized from
>   a nib file. Go into `SubViewOneController.m` and un-comment the code
>   starting with:
>
> ```
> - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
> ```
>
> change:
>
> ```
> [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> [super initWithNibName:@"SubViewOne" bundle:nil]
> ```
>
> then it should load the associated view object from the nib file of
>   that name.

Unfortunately there are no such expressions in the code. He must have been referring to the snippets of code that were automatically generated by xCode that I don't have avalaible anymore. Could you please tell me with a short explanation what exactly to change now?

Answer (score 1):

try copying this into your SubViewOneController.m

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"SubViewOne" bundle:nil]) {
      // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I would override `initWithNibName`.  Why not just call `initWithNibName` when you need that view?  For example, in the following code, I am getting a new view

```
-(void) GetHighScoresView
{
 if (highScoresTableViewController == nil) {
  HighScoresViewController *aView = [[HighScoresViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HighScoresView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  self.highScoresViewController = aView;
  [aView release];
 }
}
```